# Simple line editor

Tags: beginner, c, console, windows, text-editor

I'm self-learning C now and I want to find out if my code is good and clean or kinda messy. This exercise is a simple line editor. please tell me what do you think, If anything needs to be better in the terms of style and bugs. for the program purpose itself, I don't intend to change or add features to it.
please tell me what you think.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>


char *_ctrlLine = "#################################################";
int _cursor = 0, _maxLines = 0;


void clearBuffer(void) {
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}

void addLine(char ***lines) {
    system("CLS");

    char strBuffer[30], *tempLine = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(strBuffer) + 1));
    printf("enter your row:\n>%3d ", _cursor+1);
    gets_s(strBuffer, 30);
    strcpy_s(tempLine, strlen(strBuffer) + 1, strBuffer);

    _maxLines++;
    char **temp = *lines;
    *lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (_maxLines+2));

    for (int i = 0; i < _cursor+1; i++)
        (*lines)[i] = temp[i];
    (*lines)[_cursor] = tempLine;
    for (int i = _cursor; i <= _maxLines; i++)
        (*lines)[i+1] = temp[i];
    free(temp);

}

void deleteLine(char ***lines) {
    system("CLS");

    if (_maxLines == 0 || _cursor == _maxLines) {
        printf((_maxLines == 0) ?
            "no lines to delete.. YET!\n" :
            "you cant delete the control line.\n");
        getchar();
        clearBuffer();
        return;
    }

    _maxLines--;
    char **temp = *lines;
    *lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (_maxLines+1));
    for (int i = 0; i < _cursor; i++)
        (*lines)[i] = temp[i];
    for (int i = _cursor; i <= _maxLines; i++)
        (*lines)[i] = temp[i+1];
    free(temp[_cursor]);
    free(temp);
}

void changeLine(char ***lines) {
    system("CLS");

    if (_maxLines == 0 || _cursor == _maxLines) {
        printf((_maxLines == 0) ?
            "no lines to change.. YET!\n" :
            "you cant change the control line.\n");
        getchar();
        clearBuffer();
        return;
    }

    char *temp = (*lines)[_cursor];
    puts(temp);
    printf("change the row above:\n>%3d ", _cursor+1);
    char strBuffer[30], *tempLine = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(strBuffer) + 1));
    gets_s(strBuffer, 30);
    strcpy_s(tempLine, strlen(strBuffer) + 1, strBuffer);
    (*lines)[_cursor] = tempLine;
    free(temp);
}

void printLines(char **lines) {
    system("CLS");

    if (_maxLines == 0) {
        printf_s("no lines... YET!\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= _maxLines; i++) {
        putchar((_cursor == i) ? '>' : ' ');
        printf_s(" %3d %s\n", i+1, lines[i]);
    }
}

void moveCursor(bool up) {
    if (up) {
        if (_cursor > 0)
            _cursor--;
    }
    else if (_cursor < _maxLines)
        _cursor++;
}

void showOptions() {
    system("CLS");
    printf_s("a. add line\nd. delete line\nc. change line\n1. move cursor up\nq. move cursor down\nz. quit\npress any key to continue ");
    getchar();
    clearBuffer();
}

int main() {
    char key = NULL;
    char **lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    lines[0] = _ctrlLine;

    while (key != 'z') {
        printLines(lines);
        printf_s("what key do you want?(o for options) ");
        scanf_s("%c", &key);
        clearBuffer();
        switch (key) {
        case 'o': showOptions();
            break;
        case '1': moveCursor(1);
            break;
        case 'q': moveCursor(0);
            break;
        case 'd': deleteLine(&lines);
            break;
        case 'c': changeLine(&lines);
            break;
        case 'a': addLine(&lines);
            break;
        case 'z': printf_s("bye bye!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ariel Ariel, Why do you cast the return value of `malloc()`?  Example: why `*lines = (char**)malloc(...`instead of `*lines = malloc(...`?

Comment: the header file: `conio.h` is not portable.  Strongly suggest using the standard C library functions rather than the functions 'exposed' via `conio.h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **`malloc`** doesn't need a cast. In fact, casting the result of malloc may lead to hard to find problems.
- **`sizeof(char)`** is guaranteed to be 1.
- Prefer taking `sizeof expression` rather than `sizeof(type)`. The reason is that such code remains valid even if the type changes. In your case,

  ```
      *lines = malloc(sizeof(**lines) * (_maxLines+2));
  ```
- Triple stars are usually frowned upon. Notice that you don't even need them. Your code never refers to `lines` per se, but only to `*lines`. This is what you care about, and that is what you shall be passing.
- `lines`, `cursor` and `maxLines` are good candidates to be bundled into a structure.
- The `strBuffer` serves no purpose. You may read directly into `tempLine`. Similarly, `changeLine` may read directly into `(*lines)[_cursor]`, avoiding memory allocation.
- `deleteLine` doesn't really need `temp`. You may modify `lines` in-place.
- A `printf(); getchar(); clearBuffer()` sequence should be factored into a function.

Answer (score 2):

Most would prefer something like `[i+1]` to be `[i + 1]`. As a general rule make sure your operators have a space each side. But since you are a bit inconsistent with the spacing it may just be a typo.

Not including `{` and `}` with your `for` loops is playing with fire and something I would discourage.

Answer (score 1):

for ease of understanding and readability:

1. separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.
2. separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)
3. follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one
   variable declaration per statement.*

============================
in general, it is best to layout the code in the sequence:

1. the prototypes for the sub functions
2. the 'main()' function
3. the bodies of the sub functions

============================
in general, variable names should not begin with `_<capital letter>` nor with `__` as such naming conventions are 'reserved' for the system
Amongst other reasons, the compiler prepends all names with a '_'

============================
the header file: `stdlib.h` exposes the prototype for `malloc()` so no need to include the `malloc.h` header file

============================
regarding:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

this is not sufficient as the EOF condition can be returned so should also be checking for EOF

============================
regarding:

```
system("CLS");
```

the 'command' "CLS" is not portable.  Suggest using a formfeed character (or better) use the ANSI terminal escape sequence for clearing the screen and moving the cursor to the 0,0 (upper left) char position

============================
regarding:

```
void addLine(char ***lines)
```

please google 'three star programmer'  then rethink the logic of that part of the program.

============================
the function: `gets_s()` is not portable, suggest using: `fgets()`

============================
when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` )

1. the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc and is 'error prone' when performing debug and/or maintenance.
2. the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.
3. always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

============================
the function: `strcpy_s()` is not portable, suggest using: `strncpy()`

============================
when writing the body of a `for()` or `while()`, etc loop, even if there is only (today) a single statement, always enclose the body in braces '{' '}' so some future (or yourself) will not be likely to corrupt the logic flow

============================
regarding:

```
char strBuffer[30]
char *tempLine = malloc(strlen(strBuffer) + 1));
```

since the array `strBuffer` contains trash and since the function: `strlen()` does not stop until it encounters a NUL byte (0x00), the result of the call to `strlen()` could return anything (depending on where it encountered a NUL byte)  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Note: several of the places where the posted code is calling `strlen()`,  from the surrounding code, it should be using: `sizeof()`

============================
there are several problems with the handling of the variables: `cursor` `temp` `*lines` and `maxLines`   amongst other things, this statement:

```
*lines = malloc(maxLines+2);
```

is only allocating a 'trivial' number of bytes.  BUT `*lines` is expected to be an array of pointers to char.  But that is not what is being allocated.

============================
regarding:

```
free(temp);
```

is hinting that ALL the pointers to the lines in the file are being copied each time a line is inserted into the file.

============================
Note: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  Several of the variable names are very misleading.

============================
in the function: `addline()`, there is a LOT of copying as a line is inserted in the text.  IMO: it would be much better to simply extend the sizeof the `*lines` memory allocation via calling `realloc()`